# Error iniciando mysql con XAMPP Control Panel

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, xampp

Estoy aprendiendo a usar bases de datos con **netbeans**, sin embargo al usar **xampp** no me deja iniciar **mysql**.

Adjunto imagen del **xampp** y además el **error log**.

Debo decir que al principio **traté de abrir el admin** para trabajar en el navegador (localhost/phpmyadmin) pero la página **nunca cargó**, cerré y volví a entrar y empezó con este error.

```
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.22 started; log sequence number 304495; transaction id 204
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-01-18 14:16:14 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

[image: error xampp]

Comment: El error log que muestras no coincide en la hora que te dio el error, y de hecho solo muestra [note], que no son errores, son simples notificaciones de lo que va haciendo.

Comment: @masterguru estoy abriendo el archivo **mysql_error.log**, cuando ejecuto en el log aparece lo mismo, nunca cambia, sin embargo eso es lo único que me aparece, nada de errores.

Comment: intenta esto, ve a archivos my.ini.  y cambia el port:  si te aparece 3306 ponlo en 3307